# Shadows not calculated properly for some of the faces in the mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, shadows

I'm running into this issue guys where I'm rendering these dark faces even though the normals are correctly placed.

I used the knife tool to cut-up the mesh for most of teh scars and cracks you see running through the faces. However I don't see what the reason for these dark faces is.

[image]

Normals are all facing in the proper direction:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That really _does_ look like normals, doesn't it? Could you show us an image in solid & wire to show geometry, maybe with face normals displayed, too?

Comment: Any chance there is another mesh/plane underneath causing X fighting?

Comment: nope...all clean. From what I can see because some of the faces (the dark ones) are slanted inwards the shadow being created is what's causing the issue....even though the light source is a sun directly placed in front of the mesh.

Comment: it really does look like a shadow. Have you tried adding an extra light or moving your light to another position to test?

Comment: yea those are some serious shadows. After restarting blender and playing around with the light (size and strength) those ended up being the cast shadows. Even though the angle of the slants wasn't big enough to cause such drastic dark shadows. Nevertheless they are shadows. Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: @Luciano I stand corrected! :D

Comment: Post your Blender File so it will be more Clear

Comment: @RobinBetts I Think its a problem with Light Bounces. Everything looks fine (Topology, Normals etc.)